# Getting "entriesInRange" from other users

Tags: clockify

I've encountered some problems using POST /workspaces/{workspaceId}/timeEntries/user/{userId}/entriesInRange

It works only if I ask for my own userid, but when I request data for other workspace users - I get 403 - forbidden - how can I change that ? I'm using account within admin group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That endpoint is used for the timesheet functionality and does not support users other than yourself, even if you are an admin of your workspace. You can however use the SummaryReport endpoint which will give you time entries in requested range, and you can set the input parameter 'me' to toggle between your and your team's entries:

https://clockify.github.io/clockify_api_docs/#tag-Summary-report

Comment: What's the difference between project and projcetIds in the query (for the first time I'm encounter non id fields)?

Comment: Use `projectIds`. Parameter `projects` is deprecated, and will be removed with next documentation update.